# Pandas: Assign value in column based on time range of the respective row (no header)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on converting csv files with no header into dataframe. I'm using `usecols` to filter column selection and declare `header=None`.

```
import pandas as pd

path = r"data.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(path, usecols=[0, 1, 3, 4], header=None)   
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Sample data :

```
{0: {0: '2022-08-06',
  1: '2022-08-06',
  2: '2022-08-06',
  3: '2022-08-06',
  4: '2022-08-06'},
 1: {0: '07:35:16',
  1: '07:35:22',
  2: '07:35:29',
  3: '07:35:36',
  4: '07:35:42'},
 3: {0: 'OK', 1: 'OK', 2: 'OK', 3: 'OK', 4: 'OK'},
 4: {0: 1.524, 1: 1.628, 2: 1.364, 3: 1.164, 4: 1.494}}
```

After that, I need to add new blank column for `working shift` data which depends on `time` data from `column index [1]`.

Here the relationship between `time` and `working shift`:

```
19500hrs to 0749hrs = 'PM' shift
07500hrs to 1949hrs = 'AM' shift
```

The question is, how can I use range of time to assign data in `working shift` column? This is what I'm working on so far:

```
ShiftID = pd.Series([], dtype=pd.StringDtype())

df[1] = pd.to_datetime(df[1])

start = datetime.strptime('19:50:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()
end = datetime.strptime('07:49:59', '%H:%M:%S').time()

for i in range(len(df)):
    if df[1].dt.time.between(start, end): # <------- I'm confuse right here
        ShiftID[i]= 'PM'
    else:
        ShiftID[i]= 'AM'

df.insert(2, "ShiftID", ShiftID) # <--- insert 'working shift' column into index [2]

display(df)
```

My desired output is something like this:

```
0: {0: '2022-08-06',
  1: '2022-08-06',
  2: '2022-08-06',
  3: '2022-08-06',
  4: '2022-08-06'},
 1: {0: '07:35:16',
  1: '07:35:22',
  2: '07:35:29',
  3: '07:35:36',
  4: '07:35:42'},
 2: {0: 'PM', 1: 'PM', 2: 'PM', 3: 'PM', 4: 'PM'},
 3: {0: 'OK', 1: 'OK', 2: 'OK', 3: 'OK', 4: 'OK'},
 4: {0: 1.524, 1: 1.628, 2: 1.364, 3: 1.164, 4: 1.494}}
```

Comment: Please add a sample with the data from your df to your Q (as text, not as a picture). Try something like `df.head().to_dict()`. Also share the desired output based on that sample.

Comment: I just update my questions. Thank you for your suggestions. @ouroboros1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
values = np.where(df[1].dt.time.between(start, end), 'PM', 'AM')
ShiftID = pd.Series(values, df.index)
```

or

```
ShiftID = pd.Series('PM', df.index)
ShiftID.where(df[1].dt.time.between(start, end), 'AM')
```

---

**update**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({0: {0: '2022-08-06',
  1: '2022-08-06',
  2: '2022-08-06',
  3: '2022-08-06',
  4: '2022-08-06'},
 1: {0: '07:35:16',
  1: '07:35:22',
  2: '07:35:29',
  3: '07:35:36',
  4: '07:35:42'},
 3: {0: 'OK', 1: 'OK', 2: 'OK', 3: 'OK', 4: 'OK'},
 4: {0: 1.524, 1: 1.628, 2: 1.364, 3: 1.164, 4: 1.494}})

am_start = pd.Timedelta(hours=7, minutes=50)
am_stop = pd.Timedelta(hours=19, minutes=49)
s = pd.to_timedelta(df[1])
df[2] = np.where(s.between(am_start, am_stop), 'AM', 'PM')
df.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 1):

you should give a look to [pandas's cut method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html).

As said above, without the raw data, it's hard to propose code, but something like this should be close to your solution (replace values between <>):

```
df["Working Shift"] = df.cut(df[1], bins=[<00:00>, <begin>, <end>, <23:59>], labels=["AM", "PM", "AM"])
```

Answer (score 1):

this one also may work:

```
import numpy as np

condition1 = [(df[0].dt.time >= start) & (df[0].dt.time <= end)]
df['ShiftID'] = np.where(condition1, "PM","AM")
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.